# Как получить текст кнопки?

Tags: java, android

Как получить текст кнопки и сравнить ее с стрингом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Текст получают методом `getText()`
- Строки сравнивают методом `equals()`

  ```
  Button button = ...;
  System.out.println(button.getText().equals("someTextToCompare"));
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
String textbutton = button.getText();
String compareString = "Сравнение";
//compareString переменная которую мы хотим сравнить с текстом кнопки
//textbutton переменная которую равна тексту кнопки
if(compareString.equals(textbutton)){//спрашиваем compareString равна // 
//textbutton
   System.out.println("Равны");
}else{//Если не равна выполняем этот кусочек кода
   System.out.println("не Равны");
}
```

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Чем ваше решение лучше чем уже предложенное?

Comment: я изменил мой кусок кода и пояснил его